# Script to turn on keyboard LED won't work automatically as a starup application

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, chmod

I'm having a problem that I don't know what else to do.
I've created a simple one command shell script with the following lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

I've given execute permission to it using:

```
sudo chmod a+x scr.sh
```

If I run it from the terminal, it runs. No errors. 
BUT if I put it on Startup it won't run on auto.
I have a CMDevastator keyboard and trying this script to turn on the keyboard LED.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I was going to ask a similar question now. :/

Comment: Hi Marcos, it's a timing issue. See the linked dup.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your script to `/etc/rc.local`, make sure you provide full path to your script before `exit 0`. Anything written after `exit 0` will never be executed.

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sh /path/to/your/script.sh
exit 0
```

Comment: This will fail by definition, since this will be overwritten by local procedures.

Comment: I'll try asap!.

Comment: This post has flagged as duplicate, please try the linked answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cronjobs Using `crontab -e` And `@reboot` Or Use `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: This will fail by definition, since this will be overwritten by local procedures.

Comment: I don't wanna use any thirdy softwares, but I'll take a look to it. I'm new in linux world. Thanks for all the help!